# Generic "get in touch" icon

Tags: icon

I usually use the phone call icons, or email, sms, and so on.

But in my case we found the need for a generic "get in touch" icon, which will lead to either email, or phonecall, or sms, depending on what is available.

Is there an icon for such a feature? Right now I'm looking at hybrid icons with a phone over an envelope for example, but while that would do the trick, I'm curious if there is anything more to find out here.

Is there an icon that exists for such an action?

EDIT: adding context to understand my question :

I have a list of contacts and in that list, each cells displays quite a bit of information : complete name, company, role, email, a couple of other tags, and 3 possible phone numbers (home/work/mobile).

All that is quite a lot to display in one cell ; it was the original design but it's just too much.

Touching a cell simply selects it and is outside of the scope of this question.

Right now, you can also tap on the phone numbers/email to send an email or call the person. Which forces us to leave enough space on the cell to select it easily (I'm in a mobile app), which makes the cells quite big on top of displaying a lot of information.

But there is zero use for our user to actually know the phone number of the contacts, in our case, we really just need a "call home", not a "call 123456789". We tried reducing it to text (call home) but changing the number to text does not solve the issue.

We then decided to simply add a button that opens a picker modally, with "Call home, call office, send email", etc. depending on what was available in the contact information. Then selecting somethign in that picker initiates the actual phone/email action and switches you in the relevant app.

We're happy with that, the cell is quite small, we can see more contacts on 1 screen, and it does not obscure the experience to hide the numbers and emails (you never really look someone up by email or phone number).

I'm talking about that button, the one that opens the picker, this is the icon i'm looking for. It's a `contact that person using whatever mean is available, which probably includes an email and at least one phone number, which could be home/office/work` button.

I hope this provides enough information and context :)

Comment: Giving us the context could help you get a more precise answer. It is a little open-ended now. Like how big is it? What's the functionality? That said it could be a `contact book` or even just a `person`. It depends on the context. Just the email icon as a link is probably enough to tell you that when you click it, you'll probably be sending email, but if it's a person icon, it might not be so apparent. Buuuuut if you have like say a menu with icons and text, a person icon next to text that says something like "get in touch" could make sense as you are typically contacting people.

Comment: I can see your point, but how does one actually get in touch except by phone or email? Is it a message? Whatsapp? What`s the actual action the people are supposed to take in order to get in touch?

Comment: I added the exact situation I'm facing, I hope this provides enough context and information :)

Comment: This question would also be a great candidate for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Funny you should say that, I've been asked to post here. I went to UX first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think merely a "conversation" icon would work well....

[image]

or

[image]

... or something to that effect.

This because the overall goal *appears* to be to contact the individual for a conversation.... regardless of the *means* of contact.

Answer (score 2):

I think the generic *Get in touch* icon is the *Contact us*, which is usually symbolized by an envelope or a telephone. The most abstract is made with two dialogue balloons:

[image]

[image]

**Add after the question edit**

What about something more generic (or basic) about communication:

[image: speaker1][image: speaker2]

- Get in touch = we would like to hear you?

[image]

Comment: I don't think the ear works because the action is them *telling* you something, not listening to something

Answer (score 2):

The generic "get in touch" icon is generally denoted by using the phone icon or the chat bubble icon, so there is no particular icon for that but, you can always use such icons as given below. It might be somewhat similar to the hybrid icon with a phone over an envelope that you have mentioned.

[image]

You can also use some customized icons as given below for the same.

[image]
[image]