# What are the best icons to represent “now” and “in the future”

Tags: icon

What would be the best icons to represent something done in the current time frame or now and something that will be done in the future?

Comment: Hi Vinnie, welcome to GD.SE, please read the first comment and the edit of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/116393/120647), I think it can be applied perfectly to your question. The most important is to provide enough reasons so that your question can be answered here and is not simply to put in google "now icon" or "future icon". Some examples about the other icons that you already use would also be a good information.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Would Play and Fast Forward buttons do?  I suppose it really depends on what they are going to be used for, which you kind of forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would answer to provide a suggestion, but mostly to highlight a resource you may be unaware of: [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/). It's a great site when stuck for icon inspiration.

In this case the noun project site most usually selects a clock face for "now". And a clock face with an arrow for "future"

It's also worth noting that both these icons can be achieved with font-awesome by using:

```
<i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-history fa-flip-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Here I am using [clock](https://fontawesome.com/icons/clock?style=regular&from=io) and [history](https://fontawesome.com/icons/history?style=solid), but flipping history to represent "future".

[image]